# Is this SMTP address specification valid?

Tags: validation, header, smtp, specifications

Does the following SMTP From header body represent a valid address specification as received by an SMTP server during an e-mail submission session.

```
"I robot" <robot@domain.com>[SP]
```

[SP] is the space character.

Looking at RFC822 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-3.2 and then https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-6.1 I think the trailing space breaks the specs. Am I right?